# jQuery show / hide panel and then hover over content within a panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I've got an item list where I want to show a related panel if the item list item is hovered over. I've got it working but the issue is that I cannot then hover over content within the panel once I've hovered over the linked list item for obvious reasons as I use a `mouseleave` function.

I've been at this for a few days and cannot work out the logic of what needs to be done to leave the related panel open so I can hover over it and click a read more link within it.

I tried adding a class on the hover state to the panel but that did not seem to work either.

My HTML is:

```
<div id="item-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="item-1">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="item-2">Item 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="panel-1" class="panel">
     <h2>This is panel 1!</h2>
    <a href="#">read more 1...</a>
</div>

<div id="panel-2" class="panel">
     <h2>This is panel 2!</h2>
    <a href="#">read more 2...</a>
</div>
```

My basic jQuery is:

```
$('#item-1').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#panel-1.panel').toggle();
});

$('#item-1').mouseleave(function () {
    $('#panel-1.panel').toggle();
});

$('#item-2').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#panel-2.panel').toggle();
});

$('#item-2').mouseleave(function () {
    $('#panel-2.panel').toggle();
});
```

... and then I have some CSS where the panels are set to `display: none` to begin with. Note, if neither list item links are hovered then the panels should go away if one had been open previous to that.

[**Fiddle demo here...**](http://jsfiddle.net/highrockmedia/7YeYZ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the only real way to approach this is to wrap the hidden elements in the element that you are hovering, so that the mouseleave event can be tied to the wrapper.

LINK UPDATED:
[here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YdPm5/4/)

I also used data attributes on the elements to track which panel to open.
This way, you only need the following code:

```
$('#item-wrapper a').mouseenter(function (e) {
    if ($(this).data('panel')) {
        $('.panel').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).data('panel')).show();
    }
});
$('#item-wrapper').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.panel').hide();
});
```

EDIT: added a conditional to make sure anchor tags in the panels don't trigger the hover event.

Comment: It's fine until I hover over a link within the panel and then it triggers the panel to hide.

Comment: This seems like an ultra elegant solution but the issue is I'm in a legacy site. I'll take a guess and say that the HTML5 `data-` attribute won't work in a legacy XHTML site? Is there any other way around this, perhaps use a `rel=` attribute sort of in a similar way?

Comment: if you're using a strict doctype, no, the data attributes are not valid xhtml. you could instead, use classes to achieve the same purpose. i.e. use `.hasClass()` to check for an overall class you could add to the triggering elements, and use a different ID, something like 'panel-item-1' or something so you could select the correct panel. But as you mentioned in the other answer, if you're not able to move the panels, this solution won't work, since it requires the panels to be moved inside the item-wrapper div.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

1. User a hover event handler on the `li`, not the `a`.
2. This allows you to move your content into the `li`s, so that hovering on the content means you're still hovering over its parent, the `li`.

**jQuery**:

```
$('#item-1').parent().hover(function () {
    $('#panel-1.panel').toggle();
});

$('#item-2').parent().hover(function () {
    $('#panel-2.panel').toggle();
});
```

[Forked jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hJzzP/)

Comment: You should mention that you've moved the `div`s inside the `li` rather than after the `ul`.  This is a key point.

Comment: Thanks, clarified that.

Comment: @JamesMontagne has a good point.  I need to have the dom structure as it is in my example, that's what makes this a bit tricky.  This is a reduced test case for my CMS and the content panels cannot be under the actual list item links.

Comment: @DannyEnglander can you dynamically change the DOM on page load with jQuery?

Comment: @NeilS - I could possibly I suppose using an appendTo but it might have some caching implications. I think I'd rather not at this point.

Comment: @DannyEnglander with your hands tied like that, I don't think there's an elegant solution without using kludges like timeouts.