# HTML/JQuery show/hide panel on hover

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am fairly new to HTML with some PHP thrown in for MSSQL queries, but I would like to add some additional functionality to a page I am building that may need some jquery.

My question: How can I have the Primary Panel, shown in screen shot below, show/appear when I hover over 'View Details' of the 'Jobs Today' panel and hide when the cursor moves from 'View Details'? At the moment its always visible. I have included some code snippets to show how each section is built.

[image: Screeny of the page so far]

Build Jobs panel:

```
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-5x"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                <div class="huge"><?php echo $jobCount ?></div>
                                    <div>Jobs Today</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                            <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Build Primary Panel (yet to be populated with job info)

```
            <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Primary Panel
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt est vitae ultrices accumsan. Aliquam ornare lacus adipiscing, posuere lectus et, fringilla augue.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    Panel Footer
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

As always, thanks in advance. Hopefully I haven't missed anything :)

EDIT: I now have the hide working. The details panel is shown when the page first loads, I hover over the 'View Details' and when I leave the panel disappears. What am I missing. Here is the code as is now:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
   <div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-5x"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
        <div class="huge">
          <?php echo $jobCount ?>
        </div>
        <div>Jobs Today</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="jobs-wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="panel-footer" data-panel="job-details">
        <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
        <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>             </span>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- /.row -->

<div class="col-lg-4">
 <div class="panel-primary-jobs" id="job-details">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    Jobs Today
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>This is where Job info will go</p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-footer">
        Close
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

and the jquery

```
$('#jobs-wrapper a').mouseenter(function(e) {
if ($(this).data('panel')) 
 {
  $('.panel-primary-jobs').hide();
  $('#' + $(this).data('panel')).show();
 }
});
$('#jobs-wrapper').mouseleave(function() 
 {
  $('.panel-primary-jobs').hide();
 }
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery show / hide panel and then hover over content within a panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474972/jquery-show-hide-panel-and-then-hover-over-content-within-a-panel)

Comment: I have read through the example and answer of this original post. I have also had a play with the fiddle, as well as making my own but I just cant get it to work.
Here is my fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/3mght6m9/12/]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add some classes to tell apart the `.header` from the `.details`:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary header">...</div>

<div class="panel panel-primary details hidden">...</div>
```

And then:

```
$('.primary-panel .panel-footer')
  .hover( () => $('.details').show(), () => $('.details').hide())
```

The first function is the `hover in` handler and the second one, the `hover out`

Comment: Sorry, I can't make sense of this. I have added in the `.header` and `.details`as well as the js function, but the panel just doesn't show.

Comment: Hello again. I have got my head round this...almost. I have edited my original post with some new code that is hiding the panel, however the panel is visable when the page first loads. It does hide when I leave the View Details div but doesnt re-appear either when re-entering it. Thanks always :)

Comment: Another evening spent playing! No joy though.

I have a fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/3mght6m9/4/]

Comment: @Jimdog, your fiddle does not work since you use jquery without enabling it. Click on Javascript settings in your fiddle and choose a jquery framework. Similarly add the Bootstrap CSS and JS as external references.

Comment: @Jedi I have added a JS framework and cross checked everything in fiddler against a working example thats shown in the linked article. No joy.

latest URL:https://jsfiddle.net/3mght6m9/15/

Comment: So, I have the show and hide working. However, after filling the div with info, I think having it scrollable would be good, so I would need it to remain open when I move into it, rather than closing when I leave the 'View Details'

I have a fiddle of what I have so far, please dont worry about the CSS.

Here is the link: [https://jsfiddle.net/3mght6m9/21/]
feel free to have a play :)

Comment: I have a working bit of code, although its not the tidiest.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3mght6m9/22/

Comment: new code, working how I need it to.

`$("#jobs-wrapper").mouseleave(function() {
      var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $("#jobs-details").hide();
      }, 500);
      $("#jobs-details").mouseenter(function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
      });
});

$("#jobs-wrapper").mouseenter(function() {
  $("#jobs-details").show();
    $("#jobs-details").mouseleave(function() {
      $("#jobs-details").hide();
 });
});`